# Project Euler 106: Necessary and sufficient conditions

Tags: combinatorics, project-euler

**Problem Statement**

> Let S(A) represent the sum of elements in set A of size n. We shall call it a special sum set if for any two non-empty disjoint subsets, B and C, the following properties are true:
>
> 1. S(B) ≠ S(C); that is, sums of subsets cannot be equal.
> 2. If B contains more elements than C then S(B) > S(C).
>
> For this problem we shall assume that a given set contains n strictly increasing elements and it already satisfies the second rule.
>
> Surprisingly, out of the 25 possible subset pairs that can be obtained from a set for which n = 4, only 1 of these pairs need to be tested for equality (first rule). Similarly, when n = 7, only 70 out of the 966 subset pairs need to be tested.
>
> For n = 12, how many of the 261625 subset pairs that can be obtained need to be tested for equality?

**What I've already done:**

Sets are represented as lists sorted in ascending order. A list $X$ of length $n$ is addressed as $X[0],\ldots,X[n-1]$. Set cardinality is denoted by $|\cdot|$.

As given, consider $A$ to be a set of size $n$, and $B$ and $C$ to be disjoint nonempty subsets of $A$. W.l.o.g. consider last($C$) $>$ last($B$), because Rules 1 and 2 are satisfied by ($B$,$C$) iff they are satisfied by ($C$,$B$).

Case 1: $|B| > |C|$. Since $A$ already satisfies the second rule (in the problem statement), $S(B) > S(C) \Rightarrow S(B)\neq S(C)$. Hence, testing is not required for such (unordered) pairs ($B$,$C$).

Case 2: $|B| = |C| = x \leq n/2$. Consider the set $B' = \{\text{index of }B[i]\text{ in }A: 0\leq i < x\}$ and $C'$ defined similarly for $C$. Note that we must have last($B'$) < last($C'$) because $A$ was sorted ascending.

Claim (part of Case 2): If $B'[i] < C'[i] \;\forall\; 0\leq i < x$, then Rule 1 is satisfied.
This claim is easily proved.

**Question:**
The above claim can be proved in an "if .. then .." form. However, I assumed that it is actually true in the form " .. iff ..", wrote the code and voila! The answer matches! (I checked by hand for cases $n=7$, $n=4$; there will also be binomial coefficients, see the code below for details).

However, I am unable to come up with a proof for the " .. if .. " statement.  In other words, (why) does the (unordered) pair require checking iff $B'[i] < C'[i]\; \forall\; 0\leq i < x$?

I intuitively feel that there might be some way to use Rule 2 repeatedly to derive some additional constraints, i.e., there might be more pairs which need not be checked apart from the ones satisfying our criteria.

**Code** (Python 2.7.10)

```
from scipy.misc import comb

def check_not_reqd(b,c):
    x = True
    for (bn,cn) in zip(b,c):
        x = x and (bn < cn)
    return x

def recurse(b, length, depth, start, end):
    count = 0
    if depth == 0:
        for b[length-1] in range(start, end):
            c = [x for x in range(2*length) if x not in b]
            if (not check_not_reqd(b,c)):
                count = count + 1
        return count
    else:
        for b[length-1-depth] in range(start, end):
            count = count + recurse(b, length, depth-1, b[length-1-depth]+1, end+1)
        return count

print(sum([comb(12,t)*recurse([0 for s in range(t/2)],t/2,t/2-1,0,t/2) for t in [4,6,8,10,12]]))
```

If the recurse function seems a bit difficult to comprehend, here is an "unfurled" version for `t=8`

```
tot = 8
count = 0
b, c = [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,7]
start = 0
end = tot/2
for b[0] in range(start,end):
    for b[1] in range(b[0]+1,end+1):
        for b[2] in range(b[1]+1,end+2):
            for b[3] in range(b[2]+1,end+3):
                c = [x for x in range(0, tot) if x not in b]
                if(not check_not_reqd(b,c)):
                    count = count + 1
print(count)
# count == recurse for t = 8
```

Comment: I asked something related to this before, this might help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1350247/disjoint-set-sum-problem

Comment: @ADG, yes it is the same problem. However, here I've figured out how to solve the problem (which would answer your question) but I do not have a complete proof of correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you don't need to check the pair if either $|B| < |C|$ or indices of $C$ dominate the indices of $B$. The question is, why we have to check *all* the other pairs of sets. To resolve that problem, for a given pair $(B',C')$ we will construct a set $A$ such that $S(B) = S(C)$ which happens only for these two sets.
We assume that $\operatorname{last}(B') < \operatorname{last}(C')$.

There are four things we need to address:

1. The numbers ensure property $(2)$.
2. The numbers have actually the given indices in $A$, that is $a_i < a_{i+1}$.
3. All the indices of $B'$ and $C'$ have to be used, and nothing more.
4. The indices of $B'$ and $C'$ cannot be mixed.

The main idea is to use $$a_i = (n^n)^{n^3} + (n^n)^{n^2}\cdot p_i + \sum_{0\leq k < n} (n^n)^{k}\cdot w_{i,k},$$ where the first component takes care of $(1)$, $p_i$ takes care of $(2)$ and $w_{i,k}$'s handle $(3)$ and $(4)$.

**Part I: $p_i$**

Let $\alpha = S(B')-S(C')$. If $\alpha \geq 0$ then we set
\begin{align}
p_i &= n^3 + i & \text{ for }i < \operatorname{last}(C') \\
p_i &= n^3 + i + |\alpha| & \text{ for }i \geq \operatorname{last}(C')
\end{align}
Otherwise, let $\beta' = \max\{ i \mid B'[i] > C'[i]\}$ and $\beta  = B'[\beta']$ and use
\begin{align}
p_i &= n^3 + i & \text{ for }i < \beta \\
p_i &= n^3 + i + |\alpha| & \text{ for }i \geq \beta
\end{align}

Note, that $p_i < p_{i+1}$ and $\sum_{i\in B'} p_i = \sum_{i \in C'}p_i$.

**Part II: $w_{i,k}$**

Set
\begin{align}
w_{i,i} &= |B'|      &&\text{ for any } i \\
w_{i,k} &= 1         &&\text{ if } (i,k) \in B'\times C' \cup C'\times B' \\
w_{i,k} &= 0         &&\text{ otherwise } \\
\end{align}

and observe that to have equal sums

- you can't take any element of $A \setminus (B \cup C)$, because of $w_{i,i}$ cannot be matched by any other element,
- if you take any element of $B'$, then to match its $w_{i,i}$ only the elements of $C'$ can be used,
- there are only $|B'| = |C'|$ elements that could match $w_{i,i}$ so all the elements of $C'$ have to be used.

Thus, the only pairs with equal sums are $(\varnothing,\varnothing)$ and $(B',C')$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Isn't $\gamma = 1$ by construction? $|\{i \in B' | i \geq \beta\}| = |\{\beta, \ldots, \text{last}(B')\}|$. We must also have $C'[\beta'] < \beta < B'[\beta'+1] < C'[\beta'+1]$, which gives $|\{i \in C'| i \geq \beta\} = |\{C'[\beta'+1],\ldots,\text{last}(C')\}|$.

Comment: @theindigamer You are correct, that was the reason behind $\max$, but somehow I have lost it along the way ;-)

Comment: Okay. Now consider the case $\alpha < 0$ and $i = \beta-1$. Then, $p_i < p_{i+1}$ iff $-\alpha = |\alpha| < 1$, but we needn't have $|\alpha| < 1$...do you mean $|\alpha|$ instead of just $\alpha$?

Comment: @theindigamer You were correct again ;-)

Comment: Sorry it took me some time to work out the last few steps. Many thanks for the proof! The construction is very clever, I definitely couldn't have thought of it on my own.

Comment: @theindigamer No problem, you are welcome $\ddot\smile$